# regex python multiline

Tags: python, regex, multiline

how can i search for patterns in texts that cover multiple lines and have fixed positions relating each other, for example a pattern consisting of 3 letters of x directly below each other and I want to find them at any position in the line, not just at the beginning for example. 
Thank you in advance for the answer!

Comment: The problem is that I established already a regular expression which is able to find this pattern, for example with re.compile(r"(.*)x(.*)\n(.*)x(.*)\n(.*)x(.*)). This finds now 3 letters of x in 3 lines below each other but the horizontal x positions in the line are not explicitely the same (the x´es are not explicitely below each other), so how can I establish this boundary condition? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should include your `Input` and your `Desired Output` so people who answer don't have to guess based on sentences

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem you are asking about is "Find patterns that appear at the same offset in a series of lines."

I do not think this describes a *regular language*, so you would need to draw on Python's extended regex features to have a chance at a regex-based solution. But I do not believe Python supports sufficiently extended features to accomplish this task [1].

If it is acceptable that they occur at a particular offset (rather than "any offset, so long as the offset is consistent"), then something like this should work:

`/^.{OFFSET}PATTERN.*\n^.{OFFSET}PATTERN.*\n^.{OFFSET}PATTERN/`, using the `MULTILINE` flag so that `^` matches the beginning of a series of lines instead of just the beginning of the entire text.

[1] In particular, you could use a backreference to capture the text preceding the desired pattern on one line, but I do not think you can query the *length* of the captured content "inline". You could search for the same leading text again on the next line, but that does not sound like what you want.